# Creating Separate Class for Functions

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to create a loader/handler class but I can't seem to get the functions to show up in other classes. I imported the class into my index.js and I am trying to call the functions but they do not work.

This is what I am doing in my index.js but no functions appear.

```
import * as QueryHandler from "./src/api/QueryHandler";
QueryHandler.
```

Here is my query handler class.

```
class QueryHandler{
    constructor();

    createConnection() {
        const client = new ApolloClient({
            // uri: url
        });
    }
}
exports.QueryHandler = QueryHandler;
```

I want to be able to call the createConnection method in the index.js file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `createConnection` function you've written is a method on the class instance. This means you first have to instantiate a new QueryHandler, and then call the function on that instance:

```
const handler = new QueryHandler();
handler.createConnection()
```

---

Alternatively, you can write it as a static method. This means you can call it on the class directly, without having to instantiate it:

```
// QueryHandler.js
class QueryHandler{
    static createConnection() {
        const client = new ApolloClient({
            // uri: url
        });
    }
}

export default QueryHandler;
```

```
// index.js
import QueryHandler from "./src/api/QueryHandler";
QueryHandler.createConnection()
```

---

A third option would be to forgo classes entirely, and just export the function. This is the easiest:

```
// QueryHandler.js
function createConnection() {
    const client = new ApolloClient({
        // uri: url
    });
}

export { createConnection };
```

```
// index.js
import { createConnection } from "./src/api/QueryHandler";
createConnection()
```

Comment: Glad to help! If it solved your problem, I'd appreciate it if you mark my answer as accepted.